# Resizing the user control dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dynamic-resizing

I'm trying to resize the panels which I've created dynamically. While resizing, the panels' borders snap the grid. But it's width/height doesn't change as it should ideally. As long as the mouse pointer is on the anchor, the width/height keeps changing.Here is my code. How should I solve this issue?

Tile.cs (This is a User Control.)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Tile : UserControl
    {
        bool mouseClicked = false;
        int pixels = 16;

        public Tile()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ShowHideAnchorPoints(true);
        }

        private void ShowHideAnchorPoints(bool flag)
        {
            rightAnchor.Visible =
            leftAnchor.Visible =
            topAnchor.Visible =
            bottomAnchor.Visible = flag;
        }

        private void Anchor_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseClicked = true;
            ShowHideAnchorPoints(false);
        }

        private void Anchor_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseClicked = false;
            ShowHideAnchorPoints(true);
        }


        private void topAnchor_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (mouseClicked)
            {
                Location = GridSnapY(Location, e.Y);
                Height -= e.Y;
            }
        }

        private void rightAnchor_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseClicked)
            {
                int width = (sender as Panel).Right + e.X;
                Width = SnapWidth(width);
            }
        }

        private void bottomAnchor_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseClicked)
            {
                int height = (sender as Panel).Bottom + e.Y;
                Height = height;
                Height = SnapHeight(height);
            }
        }

        private void leftAnchor_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseClicked)
            {
                Location = GridSnapX(Location, e.X);
                Width -= e.X;
            }
        }



        private Point GridSnapX(Point location, int x)
        {
            Point p = new Point(location.X + x, location.Y);
            if (p.X % pixels > pixels/2)
            {
                p.X += pixels - (p.X % pixels);
            }
            else
            {
                p.X -= (p.X % pixels);
            }

            return p;
        }

        private Point GridSnapY(Point location, int y)
        {
            Point p = new Point(location.X, location.Y + y);
            if (p.Y % pixels > pixels/2)
            {
                p.Y += pixels - (p.Y % pixels);
            }
            else
            {
                p.Y -= (p.Y % pixels);
            }

            return p;
        }

        private int SnapHeight(int height)
        {
            if (height % pixels > pixels/2)
            {
                height += pixels - (height % pixels);
            }
            else
            {
                height -= (height % pixels);
            }

            return height;
        }

        private int SnapWidth(int width)
        {
            if (width % pixels > pixels/2)
            {
                width += pixels - (width % pixels);
            }
            else
            {
                width -= (width % pixels);
            }

            return width;
        }
```

Form1.cs (Here canvas is created with grid points where user can draw tile and resize it)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Tile t;
        Point locationXY;
        Point locationX1Y1;
        bool isMouseDown;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            canvas.BackgroundImage = CreatePixelGrid();
        }

        private Image CreatePixelGrid()
        {
            int width = canvas.Width;
            int height = canvas.Height;
            int pixels = 16;
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height);
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y += pixels)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x += pixels)
                {
                    image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                }
            }
            return image;

        }

        private void DrawTile()
        {
            t = new Tile();
            locationXY.X = Math.Min(locationXY.X, locationX1Y1.X);
            locationXY.Y = Math.Min(locationXY.Y, locationX1Y1.Y);
            t.Location = locationXY;
            t.Height = Math.Abs(locationX1Y1.Y - locationXY.Y);
            t.Width = Math.Abs(locationX1Y1.X - locationXY.X);
            t.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            canvas.Controls.Add(t);
            t.BringToFront();
        }

        private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            isMouseDown = true;
            locationXY = e.Location;

        }

        private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMouseDown)
            {
                locationX1Y1 = e.Location;
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isMouseDown = false;
            DrawTile();
        }



    }
}
```

Here is how the form looks after drawing the tile. Currently I'm working on top, bottom, right and left anchors only.

[image]

Comment: See these two examples: [How to drag and move shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749134/7444103) -- [Creating a resizable grid to overlay on a image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52044619/7444103)

Comment: Finally, this one [How can user resize control at runtime in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17264543/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi The resizing works properly without grid snapping. I don't understand why it works weirdly after adding grid snapping. Just the Control.Location is being slightly shifted to an accurate location.

Comment: Yet another [Draggable and Resizable Selection Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774101/3110834).